# Reformat name of some files and append time stamp

Tags: batch-file, rename

I am new to bat and I am trying to do the following without any luck.

I have several files in a folder named like this:

```
0000551127_loading_response_out_2023-03-20@12%3A04%3A09%3A0381391_c4b80c32-e19a-4520-8e96-873a5ba49228
```

I am trying to write a script that keeps the first 10 digits "0000551127" and then adds the date and the time.

I think the best way to handle it is with a for loop, but all I have been able to do is to add the time stamp at the end with this:

```
for %%f in ("%folder%\*.txt") do (
  set "timestamp=!time:~0,2!-!time:~3,2!-!time:~6,2!-!time:~9,2!"
  ren "%%f" "%%~nf_!timestamp!%%~xf"
)
```

Now, I have been reading for days and I dont know if all the changes I want to do are possible in just one command, can that be done? It has to be a bat file, I cant use any other technology.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Mariano

```
for %%f in ("%folder%\*.txt") do (
  set "timestamp=!time:~0,2!-!time:~3,2!-!time:~6,2!-!time:~9,2!"
  ren "%%f" "%%~nf_!timestamp!%%~xf"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

SET "Timestamp=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~-0,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~-5%"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%b IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\??????????_*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 REN "%sourcedir%\%%b_%%c" "%timestamp%-%%b%%~xc"
)

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR  %%e IN (??????????_*.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%b IN ("%%e") DO (
  REN "%%b_%%c" "%timestamp%-%%b%%~xc"
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Here's two different ways of doing such a rename.

The method relies on the filemask `??????????_*.txt`, meaning 10 characters, underscore, something.txt

You haven't provided an example "new filename", nor have you told us whether the 10 digits are unique so I've made assumptions which might be dangerous.

There are no doubt hundreds of items on SO about date/time formats in batch and their dependence on user-configuration. You haven't provided us with your format, so I've used mine, which is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.cc